# How do I get a code window to split vertically in Visual Studio 2008? (not HTML mode)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide

In Visual Studio 2008, it seems that **Window -> Split** only gives me a horizontal split, and **Window -> New horizontal tab group** does not allow me to edit the same file in both panes.

Note that I am talking about C# code windows, **not** HTML editing mode.

I want to edit the same file in two horizontally arranged panes.

Is this possible? Free add-ons are fine.

**Edit:** I have CodeRush Express installed, and it seems to have done *something* to my code window borders.

**Edit #2:** It's not CodeRush. I tried on VM with no CodeRush, and I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: Oh come on, there are thousands of questions tagged 'ide', this is programming related.

Comment: Probably best to do a search in the CodeRush FAQs if they have any.

Comment: By horizontally, do you mean one on the left and one on the right?  Or one on top and one on the bottom?

Comment: Make sure you've removed your horizontal split first before trying to find the vertical split as per LeopardSkin's answer

Comment: Scott, does that work for you in VS2008, or are you on 2005 too?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=344036).

The answer is:

1. Window -> New Window
2. Window -> New Vertical Tab Group

This duplicates the current tab so you'll get `[Form1.cs:1]` and `[Form1.cs:2]` tabs; and **then** you can use a vertical tab group to view them side by side.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I knew that trick, but it doesn't work for .aspx files. More and more I find myself using Emacs for even such simplest tasks.

Comment: my God, I heard Visual Studio was the best IDE ever - I installed it today and having to google basic stuff like how to split a tab is really ridiculous. Seems from the answers it was easier in older versions, so maybe I just heard it a long time ago that VS was great and things have changed since then. That said I'm impressed how lean it is and how fast it loads.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it's not CodeRush's fault.  A vanilla 2008 install only lets you do the split view with one file on the top and one file on the bottom.  The only side-by side option is the horizontal tab-group feature (with the problem of only having a file open in one of them, as you mentioned.)

The obvious workarounds would be to either make a read-only copy of the file elsewhere and use that in one tab-group, or open up a second instance of VS.  It does have decent handling of files that get changed in other apps, so having the same file open in two instances isn't a problem.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. It would be nice to not have to do either of those though.

Answer (score 2):

In VS2010 I couldn't find the Vertical Tab group button.  The workaround is:

```
1. Open Fullscreen mode
2. Click and drag the window to the far right (or left) and it should give  
   you an option to view both windows side by side.
3. Exit full screen mode and you should now have the ability to click and  
     drag windows between vertical tab groups, and it even now allows you to  
     drag to a new vertical tab group.
```

No idea why you have to jump into fullscreen first, and i seem to remember not having to do that before.

Answer (score 1):

As a one-time developer on CodeRush, I doubt that this would be caused by CodeRush Xpress. I'm currently running the latest beta of CodeRush 9.1.0 on Visual Studio 2008, and splits are working fine. However, you could certainly try uninstalling CodeRush Xpress to see if that clears up the problem. If it does, I would recommend posting in DevExpress' [peer-to-peer forums](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/).

[alt text http://diditwith.net/content_images/CRXSplits.png](http://diditwith.net/content_images/CRXSplits.png)

Comment: You're right, it wasn't coderush. However, my problem is with getting a *horizontal* split - ie, two panes side by side. Also this is with a windows forms project, not web.

Comment: @Dustin - this is waaaay OT, but.... Would you mind sharing your VS color scheme? I code on the dark side as well and wouldn't mind trying out another color scheme and from your screen shots, you have some attractive base colors.

Comment: I'm using the Faculty of the Mind theme along with the Envy Code R font:

http://iridescence.no/post/The-Official-Faculty-of-The-Mind-Visual-Studio-Theme.aspx

http://damieng.com/blog/2008/05/26/envy-code-r-preview-7-coding-font-released

Comment: Thanks Dustin; I've been using a derivation of http://www.darksideofvisualstudio.net  I'll give the Faculty of the Mind theme a whirl.

Answer (score 0):

I like the vertical tab group option.  The only thing that bothers me about it is that I cannot put the solution explorer on both windows (Or properties for that matter).  I have to navigate all on one side and move screens around.

Answer (score 0):

I found this nifty add on tool for VS 2012 that allows you to compare two files at the same time and make changes.

Check [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56f99a33-46b9-4d9e-8145-900aaba9951d) out: